# My first SQL Query - OrderBy error

Tags: mysql

I am using a MySQL query to get information from two tables and then ordering them by one field. Something about the last line is not working and the AJAX function that loads the content returns an error.

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT    id, 
           user_email, 
           meta_lastname.meta_value lastname,  
           meta_firstname.meta_value firstname 
 FROM      wp_users 
 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta meta_lastname 
 ON        meta_lastname.user_id = wp_users.id 
 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta meta_firstname 
 ON        meta_firstname.user_id = wp_users.id 
 WHERE     meta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND       meta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
    WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
    ORDER BY lastname;");
```

Something about this last bit is not right and is returning an error.

```
WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
        ORDER BY lastname;");
```

Any ideas on whats gone wrong?

Marvellous

Comment: give the exact error you are getting

Comment: You can't have two where in a query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two `WHERE` in your query:

```
 WHERE     meta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND       meta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
    WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
```

You need to use a logical operator like `AND`:

```
 WHERE     meta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND       meta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
    AND user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
```

Also, you probably have to order by the original name `meta_lastname.meta_value` not the alias `lastname`.

Answer (score 1):

order by the full column name, not the alias.

```
ORDER BY meta_lastname.meta_value
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the semicolon. Try `ORDER BY lastname");` Else try without the order statement.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change the second "WHERE" to an "AND".